# Does an official list of tier 1 ISPs exist?

Tags: bgp, internet

I'm trying to find an official list of tier 1 ISPs. I found a list on Wikipedia but can't quite understand how it was compiled, it just lists AS rank as a source.
I also found some other websites that provide a list but don't cite a source.

Comment: Sorry, resource recommendations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard defining 'tier 1'. So no, there's no formal list. There are many slightly different interpretations on what a tier 1 is.